# Place vs. position when talking about work

Tags: difference

"John has been offered a *place/position* at Leeds University".

"Kate applied for a *place/position* last month".

I thought 'position' should be used in the second sentence and both options were right in the first one. Am I wrong? What is the difference between 'position' and 'place'?

Comment: A _place_ at university would be assumed to mean 'as a student', while a _position_ would be a job there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **position** in a company or organization is a **job**.

If you get a **place** in a *team*, on a *committee*, or on a *course of study*, for example, you are accepted as a member of the team or committee or as a student on the course. That's why, as Kate has mentioned in her comment, "John has been offered a place at Leeds University" would mean that John has been accepted as a student.